# Filter using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of divisions;

```
<div id="people">
  <div>
    <p>Joe Blogs</p>
    <img src=".." />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Jane Doe</p>
    <img src=".." />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to have an input text box, which when typed in, it will search through the divisions (in the p tag) and if the string matches in part or whole it will show the division, otherwise hide all the non matching divisions.

How would I best go about this using jQuery?

Many thanks?

Comment: What is the match done on? I assume the text of the `<p>` element. Also, can you show the code you have so far.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of the list, the [:contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) does a good job.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LFSQS/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#filter").on("keyup",function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var people = $("#people > div");
    if (val=="") people.show();
    else {
      people.hide()
      $("#people > div:contains('"+val+"')").show();
    }
  });
});
```

This is case *sensitive* by the way
For a clever case *in* sensitive method, look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936066/295783

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/UQzcS/)

[REFERENCE](http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/09/live-text-search-highlight-using.html)

```
var results = [];
$("#people p").each(function(){
   results.push($(this).text());
});

jQuery('#filter').on('keyup', function(event){
    var term = jQuery(this).val();
    var htm = '';
    jQuery('#result').empty().hide();

    //Keys with codes 40 and below are special (enter, arrow keys, escape, etc.), Key code 8 is backspace.
    if(event.keyCode > 40 || event.keyCode <91  || event.keyCode == 8 ||
      event.keyCode == 20 || event.keyCode == 16 || event.keyCode == 9 ||
      event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 39 ||
      event.keyCode == 40) {
        for(x in results){
            var match = results[x];
            if(match.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) != -1){
                var o = '<b><u>'+term+'</u></b>';
                var a = match.replace(term, o);
                htm += '<li>'+a+'</li>';
            }
        }
        var output = '<ol>' + htm + '</ol>';
        if (htm.length > 0) {
            jQuery('#result').show().append(output);
        }
    }
    if(term.length == 0){
        jQuery('#result').empty().hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to filter data using javascript objects (you get data from server, filter them and display with templating engine (jsrender or anything else)).

For your example it could look like:

```
var timer,
    items = $('#people > div');

var refreshFilter = function(txt) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var showItems = items.find("p:contains('" + txt + "')").closest('div').show();
        items.not(showItems).hide();
    }, 200);
};

$('#search').keyup(function () {
    refreshFilter(this.value);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rptgf/

Comment: I like the .not here. I wanted to see if I could chain the :contains