# jQuery - case insensitive value within :not selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**I am selecting a list of table rows within my document.**

The following code selects:

1. All table rows...
2. That contain a DIV with class `.val-string`
3. With a child `input` that holds the value "null".

`$('tr').children('.val-string').children('input'):not([value!=null])').each(function(k,v) { });`

This works for selecting those inputs that contain the value "null", but I also want it to work with "Null", "NULL" or even "nUlL".

I have tried using:

`... children('input'):not([value.toLowerCase()!=null])') ...`

amongst other variations/placements of the `toLowerCase()` function.

**Basically, can what I ask for be performed in one line of code like the one I'm trying to execute above?**

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector) seems to suggest using a *modified* `:contains` function, but I don't want to change this function for all my code as it is used elsewhere and requires case sensitivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no selector for **`or`** but you can use `filter`

```
$('tr .val-string input').filter(function(){  
    return this.value.toLowerCase() =='null';
}).doSomething();
```

Comment: This is perfect! I doubt an edit request would go through, so could you change .doSomething() to .each(function(key,value) { // Do something with $(this) }); for the final answer in case anyone else comes along? Thanks very much!

Comment: really irrelevant.. `doSomething()` can be any jQuery method including `each` and chances are you don't even need to use `each`... what are you wanting to do with them?

Comment: No worries - hide each of the matched rows using $(this).parent().parent().hide() :) [IF another attr within that tr is 'highlighted' for example]

Comment: Don't need each for that... just change `doSomething` to `closest('tr').hide()`. Will affect all matching rows with those input tags

Comment: Yep, `closest('tr').hide()` does away with having `.parent().parent()`. Thanks for simplifying my code and teaching me in the process - much appreciated!