# Case-insensitive contains

Tags: jquery, contains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)

I tried to look everywhere online for a way to use the `contains` jQuery selector in a case-insensitive manner, but I couldn't really find any that actually functioned with the latest version of jQuery.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Did you try the [first google result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)?

Comment: @asad I did. It didn't function for me with the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: @user40531 It works with 2.0.0b http://jsfiddle.net/rSPU7/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a custom implementation:

```
$.expr[':'].icontains = $.expr.createPseudo(function( text ) {
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return function (el) {
        return ~$.text(el).toLowerCase().indexOf( text );
    }
});
```

Use it like this:

```
$(':icontains(SoMeThInG)');
```

---

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CTg86/

Comment: @Explosion Pills - `~` in this case gives the 1's compliment of `$.text(el).toLowerCase().indexOf( text )`. But why?

Comment: http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/

Comment: @Barmar - Thats clear. This means it'll return 0 if not found or a negative number if found ?

Comment: @techfoobar Yeah, basically turns -1 falsy and anything else non falsy.

Comment: @Asad - Ahh, right. Ok. Now thats a cool usage of `~`. I would've writtena stupid if or a ternary.

Comment: But looky here, it doesn't work! http://dumbsearch.com/stackoverflow.php

Comment: @user40531 - You're using an outdated version of jQuery (1.4.2)