# How to make jQuery filter(':contains("XXX")') Case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7.1. I need to make a filter(':contains("XXX")') selector case insensitive. I have tried [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector) with no luck means it is not working. To be precise, $('div:contains') works but  filter(':contain') does not

Comment: How come the listed solutions didn't work? They **should**.

Comment: In fact, I didn't check the linked questions but you really should precise what's your problem with the answers, as suggered by @VisioN. Or this question might be closed.

Comment: Please be more specific, do you need 1) the selector to be case sensitive, or 2) the text of a known selector element to be case sensitive ?

Comment: @VisioN, Very bad that you did'nt read the question thoroughly. The link discussing :contains and I am using filter(":contains").Test it your self.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression and the filter function :

```
yourJquerySet.filter(function(){ return $(this).text().match(/XXX/i) })
```

If your string `XXX` is dynamically provided, use

```
var r = new RegExp(str, 'i'); 
var outputset = inputset.filter(function(){ return $(this).text().match(r) })
```