# jQuery - Trying to get closest li's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" rel="brand">Brand</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="fsearch">
           <input class="filter-me" type="text" placeholder="Type to search..." />
        </li>
        <li>aaa</li>
        <li>bbb</li>
        <li>ccc</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I am trying to use a function to filter the list ([Jquery filter list without case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161083/jquery-filter-list-without-case-sensitive))... but I can't get it to work. I have tried using next(), find(), closest(), ...

```
$('.filter-me').keyup(function(){
      filter(this); 
});

var filter = function(element) {

var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();
var $li = $(element).next('li:not(.fsearch)');

$li.hide();
$li.filter(function() {
   return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;}).show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$(element).closest('ul').closest('li')`

Comment: .next() only gets the immediate following sibling, try .siblings() to get all the lis, then you also don't have to exclude the .fsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a set of the `li` elements in that list other than the `fsearch`, starting from the `input`, you first go up to the `li` containing the input using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), then use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
var $listItems = $(element).closest('li').siblings();
```

Then you use your `filter` logic on `$listItems`. (I called it `$listItems` rather than `$li` because `$li` gives the impression of only being *one* item.)