# Datalist wiht enter key

Tags: jquery, html, datalist

I created the datalist. There is no error on datalist. It works well but when something entered in the input I want it to choose the closest value. For example,

```html
<input type="text" list="ilceList" id="standardInput">
<datalist id="ilceList">
  <option>Adalar</option>
  <option>Bahçelievler</option>
  <option>Bakırköy</option>
  <option>Beşiktaş</option>
  <option>Kadıköy</option>
</datalist>
```

This is my datalist. When I entered b, I make it show bahcelievler bakirkoy and besiktas in order. I want to choose first value when I press Enter key

How can I do that ?

Comment: What have you tried? :-)

Comment: Check this, may be the similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161083/jquery-filter-list-without-case-sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. You can refer it. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
$(function() {
       $('input').keyup(function(event) {
       if(event.keyCode == 13){
            event.preventDefault();
            if($(this).val() != ''){
                filter(this); 
                }           
            }    
        });

       function filter(element) {
            var value = $(element).val();
            $("#ilceList > option").each(function () {
                let option = $(this).text();
                if (option.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) {            
                    $('#standardInput').val(option);
                    return false;
                } 
            });
        };
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLx9n7fg/

Comment: Your fiddle is not using a `datalist`.