# Case insensitive search for filterring table using jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a written a code for filtering table data by searching using jquery. But the search is case sensitive. I need to make it case insensitive. Such as if i search for `a` it will show both `a` and `A` string. the table code is -

```
<input id="searchInput" value="Type To Filter">
<br/>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fbody">
        <tr>
            <td>Cat</td>
            <td>one</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dog</td>
            <td>two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cat</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>moose</td>
            <td>four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>mouse</td>
            <td>five</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dog</td>
            <td>six</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the JS code is-

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $("#fbody").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }
    //hide all the rows
    jo.hide();

    //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show();
}).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css({
        "color": "black"
    });
    $(this).unbind('focus');
}).css({
    "color": "#C0C0C0"
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this condition:

```
if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
    return true;
}
```

with this condition:

```
if ($t.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(data[d].toLowerCase()) > -1) {
    return true;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/624uS/)**

Comment: You dah best j08691! I love this . I was trying to challenge myself to figure this one out but I could not... thank you for this!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RegExp.escape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
};


...
jo.filter(function (i, v) {
    var $t = $(this);
    for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(data[d]), 'i')
        if (regex.test($t.text())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})
```