# jQuery "not contains" selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

The [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) jQuery selector allows you to match find elements that contain a specified string of text.  What I want to do seems related: I'm providing the user a "filter" text box that they can type in, and I have a set of list items.

I want to have all list items that do not contain the text the user entered in the textbox be hidden as they type.

I can listen for the keyup event on the textbox, but I'm not sure how to do two things:

1. "Invert" the :contains() selector results--I want to select elements that *don't* match, and hide them.
2. Make the matching case sensitive.

It's occurred to me that I could use [.filter( function(index) )](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-functionindex), but I'm wondering if I'm overthinking this--is there a way to accomplish this already with the selectors/functions built-in to jQuery?

Comment: Just `$(".something:not(:contains('text'))")` works. Just tried on this thread: `$(".question:not(:contains('filter2134234'))")`

Comment: For the second point: "[Is there a case insensitive jQuery :contains selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/187537/15031)"

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Assuming your user's text is stored in a variable called userString:

```
$(':not(:contains('+ userString +'))').hide();
```

will hide all of the elements not containing that string.

Edit:
If you have control over the elements in the list items, you could transform the user's text when you store it in the userString var.

Comment: I wound up using a filter function anyway, because I needed to make the search case insensitive, and there was no simple transformation of the user's input that would make it match the text of the list items.  But, I think this is the best answer I'm going to get.

Comment: I reviewed the discussion on the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector and I felt like it was simpler to just use a filter function than try and modify :contains to be case-insensitive.

Comment: Have a injection vulnerability, by example as input: `test)),other...`

Answer (score 16):

Let say that you want the list of `all <td> that` dont contains string 'Dinesh'.(assuming Dinesh is inside name Attribute)

```
$('tableId > tbody > tr > td').not("[name*='Dinesh']")
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
$("div:not(:contains('John'))").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Comment: Please add your source, this one can be found via a quick internet research.