# jQuery, selecting element that contains a specified string while not containing other

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, contains

I am using `:contains()` to find strings in a large page of text content, and all of the repeating blocks will contain strings unique to those blocks, such as a student ID. I want to combine `:contains()` with `:not(:contains())`.

The logic is as follows:
***If string contains 1234, but the word "absent" is not present, append award statement***

My goal is to combine the two selectors for a contains-but-doesn't-contain effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery "not contains" selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062085/jquery-not-contains-selector)

Comment: Possible solution: `$('div:contains(1234):not(:contains(absent))')` and [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/teeapgcz/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` here:

```
$(selector).contains("1234").filter(function () {
  return $(this).not(":contains("absent")");
});
```

Or in simple way:

```
$('selector:contains(1234):not(:contains(absent))')
```