# how to show tags with text greater than 0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how to select all `span` tags starting from 3-th span and only with numbers greater than 0 and toggleClass of `li` to block?

```
<li style="display: none !important;">
<span>1</span>
</li> 
<li style="display: none !important;">
 <span>0</span>
</li>
<li style="display: none !important;">
<span>1</span>
</li> 
<li style="display: none !important;">
 <span>4</span>
</li>
<li style="display: none !important;">
<span>1</span>
</li> 
<li style="display: none !important;">
 <span>3</span>
</li>
<li style="display: none !important;">
<span>1</span>
</li> 
<li style="display: none !important;">
 <span>0</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It is not clear what steps you have take or tried. Please clarify what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your question is that there a LOT of potential answers. Consider the following.

My examples will use Classes, `hidden` and `shown`, which is considered better practice than embedded style attribute. Yet if you must, you can do it via `.css()`:

```
$("li:gt(2) span:not(:contains('0'))").parent().css("display", "block");
```

**Example 1**

```js
$(function() {
  $("li:gt(2) span:not(:contains('0'))").parent().toggleClass("hidden shown");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.shown: {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>0</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>4</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>0</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could also do this with `.each()` or even `.map()`.

**Example 2**

```js
$(function() {
  $("li:gt(2)").each(function(i, el) {
    var cnt = $(el).text().trim();
    if (parseInt(cnt) > 0) {
      $(el).toggleClass("hidden shown");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.shown: {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>0</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>4</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <span>0</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See More:

- [jQuery "not contains" selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062085/jquery-not-contains-selector)
- https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

```js
// starting from 3-th span and only with numbers greater than 0
let spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
// take 
spans = [...spans].slice(2).filter(span => {
  const condition = +span.innerText > 0
  condition && (span.parentNode.style.display = 'block')
  return condition
  })
```

```html
<li style="display: none !important;">
<span>1</span>
</li> 
<li style="display: none !important;">
 <span>0</span>
</li>
<li style="display: none !important;">
<span>1</span>
</li> 
<li style="display: none !important;">
 <span>4</span>
</li>
<li style="display: none !important;">
<span>1</span>
</li> 
<li style="display: none !important;">
 <span>3</span>
</li>
<li style="display: none !important;">
<span>1</span>
</li> 
<li style="display: none !important;">
 <span>0</span>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for reply , how to change style to "block" for li tags according to selected spans with 0?

Comment: You are welcome, I just edit the answer please check.

Comment: Just add to the span parent a display block style.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use classes on the items instead of inline styling then just pick up the spans, `slice` from the 3rd node, and then remove the hidden class from its parent.

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

[...spans].slice(2).forEach(span => {
  if (span.textContent > 0) {
    const item = span.parentElement;
    item.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="hidden"><span>1</span></li> 
  <li class="hidden"><span>0</span></li>
  <li class="hidden"><span>1</span></li> 
  <li class="hidden"><span>4</span></li>
  <li class="hidden"><span>1</span></li>
  <li class="hidden"><span>3</span></li>
  <li class="hidden"><span>1</span></li> 
  <li class="hidden"><span>0</span></li>
</ul>
```