# JQuery Click on a div which contains a specific text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to click on a div while contains a specific text.

This is where I am:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.myclass li.active .short-text'["value=thetext"]).click();


});
```

The code above is not doing it ... How can I get this to work?

Comment: use the `:contains` selector

Comment: You have syntax error `$('.myclass li.active .short-text["value=thetext"]').click();`

Comment: even the syntax was correct, a `div` normally does not have an attribute of `value`, and even if it had, it would return the attribute value **not** the innerText

Comment: Note that `:contains()` performs case-sensitive matches ;)

Comment: Quick fix for [case-sensitive matches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/187557/1696560)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **[contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```
$('.myclass li.active .short-text:contains("someText")').click();
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the jquery method of checking if something contains a text. 
i don't know if you can use it as a click function though

```
   $('.myclass li.active .short-text:contains("thetext")').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you like.
On clicking the div, it checks the divs text contents, and in this case if it equates to "My Text", you'll get an alert.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wV3NS/)

The key here is to use `.text()` to access the element.

Answer (score -3):

Something like this should do the trick. Not sure if there is a better solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        if($(this).text() == "The text") {
            //Code here
        });
    });
});
```