# How to hide table rows containing certain keywords?

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

When reading forums, I'd like to be able to have customizable keyword filters to hide certain rows.

For example on [**this forum**](http://investorshub.advfn.com/%22Savvy-Trades-and-Investments%E2%80%9D-26218/), I'd like to hide any rows for certain usernames (3rd column).

Is it difficult to write a Greasemonkey script that could do this, only on this site?
Or is there a Firefox addon that does this kind of thing?

Comment: It would be easier to use adblock plus for this, do you have this addon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not hard to write a userscript to hide rows by keyword.

Suppose you had a table like this:

```
<table class="filterMe"> <tr>
        <th>Post</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
    </tr> <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
        <td>Fred</td>
    </tr> <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Fred speaks Greek!</td>
        <td>Ethel</td>
    </tr> <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>You keep using that function. I do not think it does what you think it does.</td>
        <td>Inigo Montoya</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And you wanted to hide rows that contained `Fred`.
Using the awesome power of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you could do that with one line:

```
$(".filterMe tr:contains('Fred')").hide ();
```

If you wanted to restrict the match to the 3rd column (Author, in this case), you could use:

```
$(".filterMe td:nth-of-type(3):contains('Fred')").parent ().hide ();
```

Please note that [**`:contains()` is case-sensitive.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326196/331508)

### Online demo: (Show and run the code snippet.)

```js
$("form").submit ( function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault ();     //-- Stop normal form submit.
    $(".filterMe tr").show (); //-- Reset row display:

    var filterTerm      = $("#filterTxtInp").val ();
    var targJQ_Selector = ".filterMe td:nth-of-type(3):contains('" + filterTerm + "')";

    //-- Hide the desired rows.
    $(targJQ_Selector).parent ().hide ();
} );
```

```css
table           { border-collapse: collapse; }
table, td, th   { border: 1px solid gray; }
td, th          { padding: 0.3ex 1ex;  text-align: left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>Filter Text:<input type="text" id="filterTxtInp" value="Fred"></label>
    <button type="submit">Filter rows</button>
</form>

<table class="filterMe"> <tr>
        <th>Post</th>  <th>Title</th>  <th>Author</th>
    </tr> <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
        <td>Fred</td>
    </tr> <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Fred speaks Greek!</td>
        <td>Ethel</td>
    </tr> <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>You keep using that function. I do not think it does what you think it does.</td>
        <td>Inigo Montoya</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Use this in a userscript, like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Hide Table Rows by keyword
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
$(".filterMe td:nth-of-type(3):contains('Fred')").parent ().hide ();
```

IMPORTANT: **You need to replace `.filterMe` with a valid selector for your site.**  [Use tools like Firebug to help you determine a unique jQuery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052467/331508) for your desired table.
**Also alter the `nth-of-type()` index as needed.**

### Or, for an AJAX-driven site:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Hide Table Rows by keyword
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements (
    ".filterMe td:nth-of-type(3):contains('Fred')", hideTargetdRow
);

function hideTargetdRow (jNode) {
    jNode.parent ().hide ();
}
```

### For multiple keywords:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Hide Table Rows by keyword
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var keywords    = [
    "Apple",
    "existentialism"
];
var keyW_Regex  = new RegExp (keywords.join('|'), "i"); //-- The "i" makes it case insensitive.

waitForKeyElements (
    ".filterMe td:nth-of-type(3)", hideTargetedRowAsNeeded
);

function hideTargetedRowAsNeeded (jNode) {
    if (keyW_Regex.test (jNode.text () ) ) {
        jNode.parent ().hide ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the awesome answer!  How do I make it so it only acts on one specific site, is that what the @include is?

Comment: Yes, you must adjust your `@include` directive(s) to match the site(s) or page(s) you are interested in.