# Hide 'Recommended' videos on YouTube sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm using this script:

```
$(function() {
$(".video-list-item").filter(function() {
     return $('span', this).hasClass('view-count');
}).hide();
});
```

Each video on the sidebar has parent `<li>` item with `.video-list-item` class, but the 'Recommended for you' ones has a child `span` with class `.view-count`.

And to inject it to the page I use Firefox addon [Custom Style Script](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-style-script/).

And this is how it looks in settings page:
[image]

But it doesn't work on YouTube, the Recommended videos still show and don't hide. I thought script don't work, but it does on jsfiddle.net:
https://jsfiddle.net/rn2jzpfc/

The Firefox extension works, because I use it for other sites to e.g. customize CSS and it works fine.

Disabling watching history on YouTube settings does not solve the problem.

YouTube source:
[image]

If you wonder why I want to hide this is because I never watched anything e.g. related to Kardashians so why I'm being forced this shit into my sidebar?

EDIT1: OK, I injected some CSS just to check if it works, and looks like all of the items on the sidebar has the .view-count class, so if script did work it would hide all of them. So I need a script that detects keywords 'Recommended' and hide based on that instead.

EDIT2: OK, I came up with this [How to hide table rows containing certain keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758115/how-to-hide-table-rows-containing-certain-keywords#31759160) but it's still not applying on YouTube page, but works on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your code is propably being run before the list is created. Try it in a `setTimeout()`