# Js search for text on page and highlight not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a script that searches for a string on a page and scrolls to it. I'd like for it to highlight the instances of the string on the page as well but that part of the script isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
$("#search").click(function(){ 
    var thing = $("input#searchItem").val();
    $(window).scrollTop($(".content:contains('" + thing + "'):first").offset().top -83);

    $('.content').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).find(thing).each(function(i) {
            this.html('<i class="found">' + thing + '</i>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're highlighting all `.content` elements, not just the ones that contain the search string.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector for how to search case-insensitively.

Comment: `$(this).find(thing)` won't work. The argument to `.find()` must be a selector, not a search string.

Comment: might consider using a highlight plugin and make life simpler

Comment: Thanks for the help with the case sensitivity. That's sorted now @Barmar