# Whole-word matching with jQuery and contains()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, userscripts, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script to selectively hide elements containing nasty stuff (a personal web sanitizer, if you will).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
//custom contains function which is case-insensitive
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
  "containsNC": function(elem, i, match, array) {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  }
});

//build array of words to filter
var nope = "long list of horrible words".toLowerCase().split(' ');

//start with an empty jQuery object
var nopeEles = $();

//add elements to filter to it
for (var i = 0; i < nope.length; i++) {
  nopeEles = nopeEles.add( $("a:containsNC('" + nope[i] + "')") );
  nopeEles = nopeEles.add( $("p:containsNC('" + nope[i] + "')") );
}

//hide all applicable elements
nopeEles.css("background-color", "white");
nopeEles.css("color", "white");
```

It works decently, but it does partial word matching, which makes short words not work. I want to filter elements containing words like "die" and "gun", without filtering those with words like "candied" or "gung-ho".

To be clear, I'm after whole-word, not exact-text. I want "gun" in the list to match not just "gun" but also "he fired a gun" and "a gun was fired". And not "gunney sergeant".

Every other answer I've seen on this topic recommends jQuery's filter(). I think I don't understand it well enough. I tried using this line in the loop, but nothing:

```
nopeEles = nopeEles.add( $("a").filter(function() { return $(this).text() === nope[i]; }) );
```

The other angle I thought to look at was fiddling with containsNC so it looks for the word, but with whitespace or end-of-string on either side. I don't really get how containsNC works, though.

Any pointers would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: change indexOf to a regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `containsNC` is just a subpar version of [this `p:containsCI()` jQuery extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326196/331508).
<sup><sub>("NC" == "no case" ≈≈ "CI" == "Case insensitive".)</sub></sup>

Use the linked jQuery extension instead and then you can use regex to match whole words like:

```
nopeEles = nopeEles.add( $("a:containsCI('\\b" + nope[i] + "\\b')") );
```

However, that question code is rather inefficient and you'll find that it slows the page because it scans the whole page 2N times (where N is the number of terms) multiplied by J substring scans (where J is the number of `<a>` and `<p>` nodes).

A more performant way is to scan each node only once by merging the regex.  See this demo:

```js
jQuery.extend (
    jQuery.expr[':'].containsCI = function (a, i, m) {
        var sText   = (a.textContent || a.innerText || "");
        var zRegExp = new RegExp (m[3], 'i');
        return zRegExp.test (sText);
    }
);

//-- Build array of terms to filter:
var badTerms    = ['die', 'guns?', 'agitators?'];
//-- Build ONE regex string for speed and efficiency:
var cnsrRegEx   = `\\b(${badTerms.join ("|")})\\b`;  //  \b is word-break regex.

var nopeEles    = $("a, p").filter (":containsCI('" + cnsrRegEx + "')");

//-- Hide all applicable elements:
nopeEles.css ( {
    "background-color": "white",
    "color": "white"
} );
```

```css
a, p {border: 1px solid lightgray; padding: 0.3ex 1ex;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>All good</p>
<p>All bad agitators</p>
<div>Some bad: <a>die</a> <a>gun</a> <a>candied</a> <a>gung-ho</a> <a>guns</a>
  <a>he fired a gun</a> <a>gunney sergeant</a>
</div>
```

Note:

1. Regex like `guns?` allows matching of both "gun" and "guns".
2. Since we are building a *string* that will be converted to regex, `\` characters must be escaped.  That is use `"\\b"` to get `\b` in regex.

Comment: I'd gotten it working with manual whitespace checking, but I was, as you predicted, beating my head against performance issues because of its intrinsically inefficient structure. I learned SO MUCH from your answer, thank you!

Comment: Can I ask why you used jQuery 2.1.0? Is there something it's better at than 3.3.1? Also, if you have any pointers for learning jQuery from a more comprehensive perspective (something I clearly need), I'd be all ears.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help.  I used jQ 2.1.0 because jQ 3 isn't in the snippets menu and the version is not critical for this.  By all means use jQ 3.3.1 if you wish.

Comment: You can try https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/jquery-tutorial/; it looks promising.  Or just try to do a task and google the various approaches for it.

Comment: Rad, thanks again, I really appreciate it. Last question, I promise - any idea why expanding the filter to `$("a, p, span").filter` doesn't seem to filter span elements?

Comment: No, I'd have to see the actual page.  Are you sure that those spans were not inside `<a>` or `<p>` nodes?  Post a new question if you have to, and include sample HTML or a link to the target page.

Comment: The spans are inside `<a>`s. If the outer `<a>` is discounted by the filter based on its textContent or innerText, are `<span>`s inside it excluded automatically too? (The page is `https://edition.cnn.com/`. I have no idea when it's appropriate to ask a new question as this is all very contextually relevant to this question...)

Comment: That page is loaded via javascript (AJAX).  Your script (and this Q&A) are for static pages. ... You ask a new question when **all** of the following are met: (1) You have a *recipe* (MCVE) for a problem that others can use to see exactly what you see. (2) You've searched Google and Stack Overflow and honestly can't find where the problem has been answered before. (3) You've tried to figure it out on your own and hit a wall.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this *kind* of problem has been addressed many times, but *maybe* not this exact variation.  So, this might be a candidate for a new question.  Either way, your answer lies in either `waitForKeyElements` and/or `MutationObserver`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I definitely didn't do 2 or 3 thoroughly enough, so I'll bear that in mind for the future. I did manage to figure out that it was an AJAX issue. I found waitForKeyElements.js, but I couldn't get it to run in the general case (any page changes, since this needs to work on all pages) without massive performance hits. Re-running the styler every few seconds works well enough for my purposes. Thanks again for all your help; this has been a wonderfully edifying learning process! :)